# Help with proof about functions and sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and $B$ a subset of $Y$. Consider the preimage of $B$, $(f^{-1}(B))$, the set of all $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \in B$. Prove that $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.
My assumption is that the function $f$ is the identity function, but I have no idea on how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: The question talks about pre-image but it is asking to prove $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$??? Is there a typo? Also $f$ need not be identity function.

Comment: One of the items of the question is to prove $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and also $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.

Comment: If $A \subseteq X$, $f(A) := \{f(x) \in Y \mid x \in A\}$.

Comment: I understand the definition for $f(A)$, but I don't quite get on how to apply it to prove the statement.

Comment: If there exists an element $y \in f(\emptyset)$, then it is the image of some element $x \in \emptyset$.

Comment: And since $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set, then $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$?

Comment: Yes, since no object $x$ can be contained in every set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can prove something you have to know the definitions. This follows from the definitions of image and preimage, and of course the properties of the empty set.

You can for example suppose that the set is **not** the empty set. This means that there is an element $c\in f(\emptyset)$, now according to the definition there must be an $\xi\in\emptyset$ such that $f(\xi)=c$ - this means especially that there's an $\xi\in\emptyset$, but this contradicts the properties of $\emptyset$ so we can by RAA conclude that the set is empty.

Similarily for $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ if it were not the empty set we would have an element $c\in f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ such that $f(c)\in\emptyset$ which is a contradiction so by RAA we have $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.